# Southern Austrian Dialect word for "Patenonkel"

Tags: dialect, austrian

I am from Southern Austria (Eastern Tyrol/Carinthia) and during my childhood we used to say *Gete* to our *Patenonkel* (like a godfather) and *Gote* if female.

Yet I remember my cousin always calling every aunt *Gote* - regardless of godmother or not. Strangely I couldn't find this version of writing anywhere else. (Good luck using Google for searching "Gete" or "Gote", NSA will think you can't even write Germany's most famous writer correct)

ostarrichi.org - which used to be my favourite tool for comparison of German/Austrian words somehow died and some tools they used to have aren't available any more. http://ostarrichi.org/dictionary-search.html?search=taufpate
Refers to 'translations' like:

- Gaid
- Taufgöt, Taufgöd

But I have never heard of these versions before. Yet the second version is according to their voting page widely accepted.
The Duden, which is listing Austriazismi uses for "Pate":

- Taufpate
- (bayrisch, österreichisch mundartlich) Göd
- (schweizerisch mundartlich) Götti

We pronounce the *e* in *Gete* like in *Fete* or *Knete*. The *Ö*-variant sounds strange to me.
Does anyone has sources if *Gete* or *Gote* appear or has ever heard the usage instead of aunt?

Comment: *Mir* gibt Google das: http://www.duden.de/sprachwissen/newsletter/duden-newsletter-vom-16-05-08

Comment: Danke, die _Gote_ wird da aufgelistet, ja. Der _Gete_ aber nicht. Es wäre interessant ob es Sprachatlaskarten dazu gibt...

Comment: Ich weiß nicht genau, was die Frage nun ist, aber vielleicht hilft [Wikipedia](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pate) hier

Comment: Ich kenne "Godi" für Patentante im Moselfränkischen.

Comment: @Em1: Die Frage ist: Welche Belege gibt es für die Variante wie ich sie aus meiner Region kenne. Wikipedia listet diesen nicht.

Comment: @Qohelet Die Region, aus der du stammst, fehlt bei Wikipedia, aber benachbarte Regionen sind gelistet und konkret "Get" und "Gettn". Das ist von "Gete" nun wahrlich nicht weit weg.

Comment: Und hier ist ein [Treffer](https://books.google.de/books?id=UQkSJsH9Lz4C&pg=PA75&lpg=PA75&dq=gete+pate&source=bl&ots=5S-fE6WN7i&sig=W2XMjShQ6PgmHgcp2vsK2ldcTj8&hl=de&sa=X&ei=ZgBbVc23H4WbsAH2q4OIDQ&ved=0CEQQ6AEwBQ#v=onepage&q=gete%20pate&f=false) für "Gete" im Schwarzwald. Hinzu kommt, dass "Gete" ahd für "Gote" ist.

Comment: Für Oberösterreich kann ich die Form "Godi" für die Patentante bestätigen.

Comment: Vgl. https://www.pfarrbriefservice.de/file/altertumliche-und-dialektale-bezeichnungen-fur-pate-patin und https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pate#Dialektale_und_altert.C3.BCmliche_Bezeichnungen . Im Sauerland wird oft "Goda" für die Patentante verwendet.

Answer (score 3):

Ich hoffe, dass es in Ordnung ist, wenn ich auf Deutsch antworte. (Ich finde es etwas seltsam, in einer Fremdsprache über österreichische Dialekte zu schreiben.)

Ich wurde 1965 in Graz geboren, meine Eltern stammen aus der Oststeiermark (Mutter aus Weiz, Vater aus Riegersburg bei Feldbach). Meine Taufpatin war eine Schwester meiner Mutter, und für gewöhnlich war sie ganz einfach die »Tante Maria«. Nur wenn es darum ging, ihre Funktion als meine Taufpatin hervorzukehren (etwa wenn sie mir etwas zu einem Festtag schenkte), dann war sie meine »Göd«.

> Weibliche Tauf- oder Firmpatin in der Steiermark: **die Göd**
>   Männlicher Tauf- oder Firmpate in der Steiermark: **der Goder**

»Goder« ist nicht nur die Bezeichnung für einen männlichen Paten. Dieses Wort ist zugleich auch die Bezeichnung für ein Doppelkinn, vermutlich weil man sich früher als Goder gerne einen wohlhabenderen Verwandten ausgesucht hat, und das Doppelkinn als Zeichen des Wohlstands galt.

Das VOR-Magazin ist eine Monats-Zeitschrift der Wiener Linien, die in allen Wiener U-Bahnen den Fahrgästen gratis zur Verfügung steht. Lange Zeit war dort auf der hinteren Umschlagseite eine ganzseitige Werbung des Wiener Juweliers Schwöd zu sehen, wo neben dem Bild einer teuren Uhr in großer Schrift der folgende Spruch stand:

> Ein jeder Göd
>   kauft beim Schwöd.

Das ist Altwiener Dialekt, und da hier das Wort »Göd« eindeutig männlich ist, ist zu schließen, dass in Wien männliche Tauf- und Firmpaten nicht - wie in der Steiermark - *Goder*, sonder eben *Göd* heißen.

> Männlicher Tauf- oder Firmpate in der Wien: **der Göd**.

Die Wiener Variante der weiblichen Form ist mir leider nicht bekannt, ich vermute aber, das es ganz einfach **die Göd** ist, aber dessen bin ich mir nicht ganz sicher.

Comment: Kam mir auch sehr komisch vor einen Text auf Englisch zu verfassen der sich mit einer Sprachvariante des Deutschen beschäftigt von der vermutlich 99% der Anglophilen noch nie gehört haben ;) . Bei uns war es eher umgekehrt. Gote hat man eigentlich immer zur Tante gesagt. Trotzdem gibt diese Antwort leider keinen Aufschluss über die in T/KTN verwendete Variante...

Comment: Wenn es dir komisch vorgekommen ist: Warum hast du dann überhaupt die Frage in einer Fremdsprache geschrieben?

Comment: Wird vorgegeben

Comment: @Qohelet Hier auf GL darf man Fragen in Deutsch und Englisch stellen.

Comment: @Qohelet: Nein, das wird nicht vorgegeben, das darfst du entscheiden. Lies bitte auch das: http://meta.german.stackexchange.com/questions/303/what-language-should-be-preferred-for-questions#830